# Error since changing my mysql database to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, notepad++

I've been inserting some foreign names into my database and I realised that I needed to change from the standard latin/swedish to UTF-8. I actually changed it all to utf8mb4_general_ci. It's displaying the characters correctly now but I've come across a slight issue. When retrieving a code from a text file (which is encoded in utf-8), it picks up the code correctly (e.g FO) but after it's saved to the database it now appears as \r\nFO. I'm not sure where these extra characters are being picked up but it's not from the file I think.

Have I done something wrong during the conversion, do I need to do something to the string before saving it or is it something to do with the way I'm saving it to the database?

I know there are lots of topics on this issue, including SO, but there are so many and I haven't found one with this specific issue.

Some edits .... I've turned on 'Show all symbols' in Notepad++ and the CR LF appear correctly at the end of the lines.

The code for inserting into the database is ...

```
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO players 
        (Name, DetailsJSON)
        VALUES (:Name, :NewDetails)");

        $query->bindParam(':Name', $this->Name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':NewDetails', $this->DetailsJSON, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();
        $this->ID = $db->lastInsertID();
```

Comment: show us the code, please (inserting part)

Comment: `\r\n` looks like a badly escaped Windows carriage return/line feed

Comment: Edited to show in the insert.

Comment: One thing that might help, is there a way to see \r\n on screen during php processing? So that I could work out at which point it's being picked up? I'm echo'ing the string out to the screen at a couple of points but it looks fine.

Comment: insert var_dump($this->Name);var_dump($this->DetailsJSON); before query. This will tell you... everything. There must be newlines or '\r\n' there

Comment: Cool, var_dump does show it, it's already there before the query. I'll try to use var_dump to track it down earlier and find out when it's being picked up.

Comment: var_dump is a winner. use it wisely though.

Comment: and don't forget about trim()

Comment: Could it be this? I'm assigning the 2-letter code (it's a country code prefix, e.g US = USA) to a string. Before I do that, I'm clearing the string, e.g $Nationality = ""  . Then I go to a function which returns the string, so I do $Nationality = Function(); (the function returns the 2-letter code). Is that just 'adding' the code to the "" when I cleared the string?

Re : trim, so I trim it after I've received the code, to clear the breaks?

Comment: Done a trim($Code) before leaving the function and that's fixed it. I guess my "" was adding the breaks? I've done it this way for ages but didn't know, I guess before UTF-8 it didn't matter or something.

Comment: create a minimal script for testing and var_dump it all. welcome to a wonderful world of php-debugging. You should be glad it's not JS or C. And no, UTF doesn't magically create newlines from "" (empty strings) there must be some other mistake/bug. Check your input.

Comment: Trim has deleted it at least, but maybe I should var_dump further back to find out where it's coming from anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, it's coming straight from the file with the chars attached. But they're not showing in Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

> and the CR LF appear correctly at the end of the lines.

CR = \r

LF = \n

so the problem is somewhere in your PHP code. You read a file, trim newlines. But without trimming some part of your code converts all CRLF to their textual representations.

Comment: I mean if I turn on the option in Notepad++ to show all codes, I see CR LF at the end of each line. I worked out that what's happening is that the way I'm splitting the lines (using Explode), it appears that the CR LF from the previous line is being attached to the start of the code. Trim fixes it.